# Align right in Run control inside TextBlock in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, alignment, textblock

How can I do this with my current implementation ? My last option would be to use a StackPanel as it would involve changing a lot of other things . Any other workarounds would be appreciated.Image below .Incase it is not clear from the image :
In one straight line,

- Extreme Left aligned : Apparels (count of defects)
- Extreme Right aligned : Nearby outlets ( Count of nearby outlets)

Things I tried :

- The flowDirection Property in RUn : did not work
- Properties like alignment/orientation that are generally there for other controls don't seem to be there for Run.

[image]

```
<TextBlock
                Grid.Column="0"
                TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource Converter1}}" />
                <Run Text="{Binding Defects, Converter={StaticResource Converter2}, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <Run Text="{Binding Outlets, Converter={StaticResource Converter3}}" />
              </TextBlock>
```

Comment: I generally use a grid for this and put two textblocks inside. One right and one left aligned. They will appear on top of each other. I don't think this is what a Run is really for, and you are using the wrong tool for the job, although maybe someone will correct me with an answer ^^

Comment: Thanks for your input. Actually, I am changing a part of the code where I have to add only the right aligned stuff. So, I wanted to stick with the existing implementation(using Run) with min changes.

Comment: What is it that makes this an expensive or difficult change? It should be really trivial to do with little to no consequences. Someone might be able to offer another solution if you can better explain why it is so important to use a run for this?

Comment: I have had success with the Grid implementation.Right now I have two columns, so it is easy to implement. But, if I have other texts that need to be accommodated in the same line in the future, I have to keep adding grid columns. Instead, with the current implementation, I am assuming that I will just have to add one line of code with a run.  I am new to WPF,so correct me if I am wrong. Just wanted to see if there existed a workaround with Run.

Comment: You don't need any Columns for the grid. Just let both text blocks fill the entire grid. You won't need to add columns to add more Runs to the respective Right and Left text blocks. You could also use a Uniform Grid.